# Как сделать высоту внешнего дива такую же, как внутреннего?

Tags: css

Суть вопроса в следующем: есть div, в котором также расположены div-блоки.

```
<div class="header">
<div class="header_nav_img"><img src="img/compass.png" width="16" height="16"></div>
<div class="header_nav_text">НАВИГАЦИОННОЕ МЕНЮ</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.header
{
margin: 0 auto;
width: 1000px;
}

.header_nav_img
{
float: left;
padding: 15px 5px 15px 15px;
background-color: #2b2b2b;
color: #FFFFFF;
}

.header_nav_text
{
float: left;
width: 250px;
padding: 15px 15px 15px 5px;
background-color: #2b2b2b;
color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Проблема в том, что внешний div имеет ширину 0 px, так как его вообще не видно. Какие стили нужно ему прописать, чтобы он по ысоте был такой же, как самый высокий внутренний?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[очищение потока](http://www.xiper.net/collect/html-and-css-tricks/css-tricks/clearfix.html)

Comment: Спасибо. Это то, что нужно.

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой **[способ](http://jsfiddle.net/Alex83/L5W3p/)**, если не хочется долго читать ...

**Это не панацея**, но в 99% случаев вполне хватает.

P.s: Кстати, статья предложенная [@SverxnovA](/users/13081/sverxnova), действительно очень полезная и познавательная, обязательно прочитайте.

Answer (score 1):

А что [display:table](http://jsfiddle.net/Cone/NJf25/) отменили??